# SAPUI5: Table - Items expanding to more than 40 Entries

Tags: javascript, sapui5, expand, items, xmltable

A Table usually requests items from a model

```
<Table id="idexampleTable" items="{exampleModel>/}" growingScrollToLoad="true">
```

Now the

```
items="{exampleModel>/}"
```

Is capped around 40 Entries, differently put, items takes only 40 Entries from the exampleModel. Now the exampleModel can have around 60 Entries, but the items - attribut will only take 40.

**How** can I expand the items-attribut threshold taken from the modelExample to ca.60 ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using an OData model. Did you try to set `growing="true" growingThreshold="60"` on your table?